# What happens if you run "open /Applications/*"

Tags: terminal, macos

I recently read in a blog post don't run open "/Applications/*" otherwise many tabs will reopen, But I ran it in Terminal and then suddenly all my apps in my Applications started to open my Mac started to heat up to 60 C and fans 1460 RPM I immediately force quit all the apps.What does "open Applications/*" do? and what is the meaning of *?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command opens all apps in the /Applications folder. The * means everything in there. For example, to open all apps in /Applications that starts with S you would type `open /Applications/s*`. Since the * is by itself that means everything.

Comment: But then why does the temperature of the Mac have to increase for opening 40 applications?

Comment: @Geek Because it requires a lot of power to run 40 apps at once